# Query where i can determine which students are bound to graduate soon

Tags: database, ms-access, relationship

I have been working on this for a solid 2 days now. i am new to microsoft access and overall database, im actually confused on how i can do the query where i can determine which students are about to graduate soon. i used chat gpt for ideas but it really doesn't do much (Im not sure if im asking the right question)

Anyway here's the tables i have [Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIKSl.png)

Any inputs on how can i create that query?

I've tried using sql codes from chatGPT and watched a youtube video about DATE/TIME where i can pick the desired start date and the end date of a particular course.

Comment: Before you start thinking about creating a query, you need a formula or a set of rules. What should the result be? A time span for each student, the number of students which will terminate until a specific date or something else? Do they have to attend all the courses in the list or only some of them? What are the rules?

Comment: Not only Chat GPT can't do a lot with these few pieces of information, we can't either.

Comment: I see i'll try to give as much info as much as possible. so anyway the list of courses i have here is has a specific years to be taken that varies from different courses. a student can pick whatever course they want. the result needed specifically is "Which students are about to graduate soon?" With my Table List of Courses, the course duration there is set to Years. which spans about 1-2 years depending on the course. Basically it just ask which students are about to finish their courses. i just need to display them when i run the Query

Answer (score 1):

I would create a sub-query which determines the last course end-date for each student. The required information is entirely contained in `STUDENTCOURSE`. Sub-query:

```sql
SELECT
    SC.StudentID,
    Max(SC.CourseEndDate) AS LastCourseEndDate
FROM
    STUDENTCOURSE AS SC
GROUP BY
    SC.StudentID
```

Now, we can combine this with `STUDENTINFORMATION` and add two conditions:

1. The last course end-date must not be before today (because then the student has already graduated): `X.LastCourseEndDate >= Date()`
2. The number of days between today and the last course end-date must not exceed a given number of days (I took 30 days as an example for "soon"): `DateDiff("d", Date(), X.LastCourseEndDate) <= 30` where `DateDiff("d", d1, d2)` calculates the number of days between the two dates.

```sql
SELECT
    X.StudentID,
    S.FirstName,
    S.LastName,
    X.LastCourseEndDate
FROM
    (SELECT
        SC.StudentID,
        Max(SC.CourseEndDate) AS LastCourseEndDate
     FROM
        STUDENTCOURSE AS SC
     GROUP BY
        SC.StudentID
    ) X
    INNER JOIN STUDENTINFORMATION AS S
        ON X.StudentID = S.StudentID
WHERE
    X.LastCourseEndDate >= Date() AND
    DateDiff("d", Date(), X.LastCourseEndDate) <= 30
ORDER BY
    S.FirstName,
    S.LastName
```

Your question leaves the question open, whether additional tests have to be made like checking if a student has completed each previous course (`CourseComplete` = true).

Answer (score 0):

A major advantage of Access is you can use VBA.  You can create Custom VBA Functions like ,StudentisAbouttoGraduate, that you can use in your queries just like the sql functions sum, max, etc.  You can do this because you can do all Database Actions from queries to opening forms with VBA.  I find it is much easier to use VBA to add business logic to your database.  For instance, here is a reproducible example you can elaborate from:

[image]

| StudentID | StudentNickName | StudentCurrentMajor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kirk | 1 |
| 2 | Mcoy | 2 |
| 3 | Spock | 3 |

| CourseID | CourseDescription | CourseCredit | CourseMajorType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Command1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | Command2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Command3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | Command4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | Medical1 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | Medical2 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | Medical3 | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | Medical4 | 2 | 2 |
| 9 | Science1 | 2 | 3 |
| 10 | Science2 | 2 | 3 |
| 11 | Science3 | 2 | 3 |
| 12 | Science4 | 2 | 3 |

| StudentCourseID | StudentID | CourseID | StarDateCompleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1/1/2402 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1/1/2403 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 1/1/2404 |
| 4 | 2 | 5 | 1/1/2401 |
| 5 | 2 | 6 | 1/1/2402 |
| 6 | 2 | 7 | 1/1/2403 |
| 7 | 3 | 9 | 1/1/2404 |
| 8 | 3 | 10 | 1/1/2401 |
| 9 | 3 | 11 | 1/1/2402 |
| 10 | 3 | 12 | 1/1/2403 |

| MajorID | MajorDescription |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Command |
| 2 | Medicine |
| 3 | Science |

[image]

In Access true is -1: normally you should format in the form or report

```
AbouttoGraduate: StudentisAbouttoGraduate([StudentID])
FormattedAbouttoGraduate: IIf(StudentisAbouttoGraduate([StudentID])=True,"yes","no")
```

| StudentID | StudentCurrentMajor | StudentNickName | MajorDescription | AbouttoGraduate | FormattedAbouttoGraduate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Kirk | Command | 0 | no |
| 2 | 2 | Mcoy | Medicine | 0 | no |
| 3 | 3 | Spock | Science | -1 | yes |

```vb
'Public Functions in a code module are reusable and can be called anywhere in Access.   
'Business Logic or State  The terms are not settled and there are many more terms
'Bare Minimum for demonstration purposes
'sorry for going halfway from simple public constants to properties, I had formatting rule issues.

Public Function GetCurrentStarDate() As Date
    'implemented to add a date check to GetCreditsNeededToGraduate but unused
    GetCurrentStarDate = DateSerial(2406, 1, 1)
End Function

Private Function GetCreditsNeededToGraduate() As Integer
    GetCreditsNeededToGraduate = 8
End Function

Private Function GetCreditsNeededToGraduateCommandProgram() As Integer
    GetCreditsNeededToGraduateCommandProgram = 6
End Function

Private Function GetCommandMajorType() As Long
    GetCommandMajorType = 1
End Function

Public Function StudentisAbouttoGraduate(StudentID As Long) As Boolean
    'setup
    Dim StudentsMajor As Long
    Dim StudentCredits As Integer

    StudentsMajor = DLookup("StudentCurrentMajor", "Students", "StudentID = " & StudentID)
    StudentCredits = GetSumCreditsbyCourseMajorType(StudentID, StudentsMajor)
    'calculation 'TODO improve by accounting for StarDate
    If StudentMajor = GetCommandMajorType And StudentCredits >= 6 Then
        StudentisAbouttoGraduate = True
    ElseIf StudentCredits >= 8 Then
        StudentisAbouttoGraduate = True
    Else
        StudentisAbouttoGraduate = False
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetSumCreditsbyCourseMajorType(StudentID As Long, StudentCourseMajor As Long) As Integer
    GetSumCreditsbyCourseMajorType = Nz(DSum("CourseCredit", "qryStudentCourseCreditwithCourseMajor", "((CourseMajorType = " & StudentCourseMajor & ") AND (StudentID = " & StudentID & "))"), 0) 'nz handles null
End Function
```

Saved query I used because it is easier and less error prone to use saved queries than cutting and pasting long strings of sql.

[image]

Comment: You could replace your If-Then-ElseIf-Else by `StudentIsAboutToGraduate = (StudentMajor = GetCommandMajorType And StudentCredits >= 6) Or StudentCredits >= 8`